# Co-authoring is not working in SP 2013 Site Collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, co-authoring

In one of my site collections on my  SP 2013 web application,the Co-authoring feature is not working while using MS WORD 2010/MS WORD 2013.
Want to know any other features/settings need to be changed/added.

Answer (score 1):

Check in - check out feature in the document library needs to be turned OFF.

Also

1.The file is using Information Rights Management (IRM) or Digital Rights Management (DRM).

2.The file is encrypted.

3.The file format is not supported. Only .docx and .pptx file formats are supported.

4.The file is marked as final. The file owner has decided to stop the process of editing or co-authoring the file and the file is now read-only.

5.Certain Microsoft Office group policy settings prevent co-authoring including the following: Disable Automerge Client Policy, Disable Co-Authoring Server Policy, and Disable Co-Authoring Client Policy.

6.The file contains an ActiveX controls. (example: from the developer toolbar, insert a date field)

7.The file contains certain objects that cannot be uniquely identified, such as an OLE object, a SmartArt graphic, chart, or Ink object. (this happens only if you edit in Office Web Application)

8.The Word document uses master documents with subdocuments, contains HTML Framesets, or is being published as a blog.

9.The Word document does not have the Store random numbers to improve Combine accuracy check box selected. (On the ribbon, click the File tab, click Options to display the Word Options dialog box, click Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings to display the Trust Center dialog box, click Privacy Options, and then under the Document-specific settings section, make sure the Store random numbers to improve Combine accuracy check box is selected.)

Comment: I have already done this . $doclib.Forcecheckout=$false using PowerShell.But for this site collection, this feature is not working.

Comment: see reply above